# bash: [ ] && (command1 ; exit), exit is never executed

Tags: bash, shell

### Question

Hi, as far as I know, in the bash, conditional statement can be shorten  using the [ ] and && (for true condition) or || (for false condition) to specify which action should be done depending on the condition.

Also, the action list can consist of multiple commands which is separated by the semicolon (;).

For example, as shown in the below source code.

```
[ ! $# == 2 ] && ( echo "Usage: $0 weight_in_killos length_in_centimeters"; exit)
```

However, it seems that the exit command does not executed after the echo prints a string.

Please go over the below source code and let me know the problem.

### Sourcecode

```
#!/bin/bash

[ ! $# == 2 ] && ( echo "Usage: $0 weight_in_killos length_in_centimeters"; exit)

if [ ! $# == 2 ]; then 
  echo "Usage: $0 weight_in_killos length_in_centimeters"
  exit   
fi

weight=$1
height=$2

idealweight=$(($height-110))
echo $idealweight

if [ "$weight" \< "$idealweight" ]; then
  echo "eat more"
elif [ "$weight" -eq "$idealweight" ]; then
  echo "fit well"
else
  echo "eat less" 
fi
```

Interestingly to me, it executes the two echo from the first conditional (shorten version) and the second conditional (if statement).

I've expected it will only print one echo message and exit because the first echo is followed by the exit command.

Comment: the `( ... ; exit )` section is run as a sub-shell (because of the parens). The `exit` applies to exiting the sub-shell. In your example case, you don't really need the parens, but you'll have to chain all cmds with `&&`, i.e. `[ cond ] && echo "msg" && exit` . If you run the revised code on your command-line, be prepared for your shell/terminal to exit. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter It's technically possible for the `echo` command to fail, in which case the `exit` would not be executed. I'd recommend just using a proper `if` statement -- it doesn't suffer from any of these weird edge cases.

Comment: BTW, you probably want to use `if [ "$weight" -lt "$idealweight" ]; then` instead of `\<`. `<` does textual (alphabetic) comparison rather than numeric. For example, `[ 110 \< 55 ]` evaluates to true, because "1" comes before "5" in character sorting order.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for a kind explanation. I have some questions about your answers. First, what do you mean by failure in echo? Did you mean the case that echo returns non-zero value as an exit value? Is it possible that the echo returns non-zero, which means failure of echo command? Second, as far as I know, for numerical comparison, double parentheses (( )) are recommended, for example "if (( 110 < 55 ))". I couldn't really understand when should I use [ -lt, -gt, eq, etc ] , [ >, <, ==], and (( )). Thanks again.

Comment: @JaeHyukLee Yes, I meant that `echo` could return a non-zero exit value. As for `[ ]` vs `(( ))`, it's rather complicated and I don't know a good single reference on the difference. And there's actually another, `[[ ]]`. Differences: `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` aren't available in all shells (just bash, zsh, maybe ksh), while `[ ]` is available even in more basic shells. `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` also have cleaner syntax (e.g. they don't require escaping `<` and `>`). `[ ]` and `[[ ]]` mostly do string comparisons, but can do integer compares with `-lt`, `-le`, `-eq`, `-ne`, `-ge`, and `-gt`.

Comment: (cont'd) `(( ))` *only* does integers, and the integer comparison operators are `<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `>=`, and `>`. Another difference: you don't have to use `$` to get variable values inside `(( ))`, they're expanded automatically. The real advantage of `(( ))` for integers is that it can do arithmetic, e.g. `(( x * 5 < z ))`. If you're just doing simple integer comparisons, any of them work ok.

Comment: Oh, another confusing thing: in `(( ))`, a single equal sign (`=`) is assignment, and a double equal sign (`==`) tests for equality. In `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`, a single equal sign is the equality test (as strings, so `[ 05 = 5 ]` is false), and double-equal is either a synonym for single equal (in bash) or unrecognized (some other shells). Oh, and read [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for a good comparison of `[ ]` and `[[ ]]` (which unfortunately doesn't cover `(( ))` as well as I'd like).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to conditionally group commands:

```
test $# -ne 2 && {
    echo "Usage: $0 weight_in_killos length_in_centimeters"
    exit
}
```